Collect pagelayout names per object in apex does not work for custom objects
Using this method to collect PageLayout names per object
    public static List<String> getLayoutNames(String objectName) {
        String sql = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('SELECT Name FROM Layout WHERE TableEnumOrId=\''+objectName+'\'', 'UTF-8');        
        String toolingEndpoint = Url.getOrgDomainURL().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v61.0/tooling/query/?q=' + sql ;
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(toolingEndpoint);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        ...
        ...
        ...

}

This works fine for standard objects but fails for custom objects with empty results. Any idea?

Here TableEnumOrId needs to be the Custom Object Id for custom objects. Use a query on CustomObject to find the ID that you need to use.
